# How to search for a string containing Arabic characters?

Tags: php, mysql, search, arabic

I have created a database which stores records, then I have created a search engine that searches the records

it works great, except for the Arabic characters, it says "no match found"

that's the search engine code

```
include('conn.php');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 

$strlen = strlen($_GET['content']);
$display_count = $_GET['count'];
$select = "SELECT * FROM letter_cast WHERE name LIKE '%".$_GET['content']."%' OR  title LIKE '%".$_GET['content']."%'";
$res = mysql_query($select);
$rec_count = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

what could be the problem?!

Comment: To be clear - does your search contain arabic characters, or does your data?  Or both?

Comment: yes, my table is UTF8, and I have both data and search contain Arabic characters

Comment: perhaps there are no matches for the Arabic characters that you are searching. Can you do an `echo $select`?

Comment: I'm sure there is some matches, because I inserted data in Arabic "تعميم" then I search for "تعميم" then it says no matches found

Comment: perhaps your data is inserting in a character set that does not support Arabic. If you do a `SELECT *` on your table, do you see that Arabic record? Can you do an `echo $select`?

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely that the encoding for the search string is wrong. Make sure you're encoding/decoding it properly with the built-in urlencode/urldecode and utf8_encode/utf8_decode if you need to before passing it on to the SQL query.

How you need do this exactly can depend on your server environment a bit, but in the simplest case it's just:

```
$content = urldecode($_GET['content']);
```

You'll also want to make sure the [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) on any previous page (that links or submits a request to the search page) has been set up correctly or the browser will not encode the request properly.

Comment: @RayanSp I edited my answer with a bit of extra info/sample code that might be useful.

Comment: I have tried what u mentioned above, still no luck, btw when I view the table from phpMyadmin, the Arabic data looks like this '&#1605;&#1578;&#1591;&#1604;&#1576;'

Comment: @RayanSp in that case you also need to run the search string through the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to convert it to look like what's in the database (after doing the urldecode). Like this: $content = htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old thread, but it can help other people,

The Php script must also be utf-8 encoded